# Create an animation which will run on any device including iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation

I have a requirement as below.

In my application, user will select 5 phots from album and will place them on 5 different views. If user wants to see them one by one as a gif, we can show the animation of those images on iPhone using [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];. But this will run on iPhone only. If user wants to send these images in animation style to his friends through email, they will not be able to see this animation as they might be on other devices from different manufactures and only images will be send in attachment.

So my question is how I can create an animation which will run on iPhone as well as on other mobile phones when send as an attachment.

Do any body have any idea how I can achieve this effect.

Thanks in advance,
VIshaL

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert your images into a single animated GIF - you will to include in your project a GIF utility source code. Good luck!